# Using coroutines to write to a log file without loosing the order the logs are in

Tags: android, asynchronous, kotlin, logging, kotlin-coroutines

I have created a custom logger to write all of my logs to file as well as to the android log. Since file writing is a blocking operation I now want to make the file-write asynchronous with Kotlin coroutines. Just wrapping the write in a coroutine doesn't work because then some logs get switched around and aren't written to file in the correct order. How can I make sure the logs are written sequentially while not blocking the main thread with file operations, optimally using Kotlin coroutines?

Comment: you can use [channels](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/channels.html) as queue for your logs

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit on that? I found them earlier today, too, but I don't quite understand how I should use them in this case. Do I have an infinite coroutine reading the channel and writing to file after reading, together with the log method launching a coroutine that writes to that channel? I was under the impression coroutines shouldn't be infinite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@IR42 said right, you should use channels for this purpose.

Use [Channel](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/-channel/index.html) and make one coroutine that is suspended and awaiting for the channel's sender to send the logs (Strings or whatever).

Using the default channel [RendezvousChannel](http://RendezvousChannel), When a sender sends a log the waiting coroutine resumes and if another sender sends the message then that next sender is suspended till the awaiting coroutine pulls the log from channel.

Example demonstrating use of RendezvousChannel

```kotlin
val channel = Channel<String>()    // Channel of Strings
val sendChannel: SendChannel<String> = channel  // Hide that this instance can receive, store this in order to send to this channel

scope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    while (!channel.isClosedForReceive) {
        val log = channel.receive()
        // process the log
    }
}

// Somewhere else
sendChannel.send("Test Log")
```

Comment: What if two senders invoke the `send` method and both get suspended because the receiving coroutine is busy saving a previous log? Does `receive` take them in the correct order?

Comment: @EmilS. edited the answer for handling channel close. [Here is tesing](https://pl.kotl.in/Jo1UJKrTL) for that and it works flawlessly for receiving in order. The output does not print immediately in the console of playground. You can copy the code and test it in your ide each line will be printed ever 100ms.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to emit logs to `MutableSharedFlow` to write logs sequentially to a file:

```
class Logger {
    // make sure `replay`(in case some logs were emitted before sharedFlow is being collected)
    // and `extraBufferCapacity` is enough to handle all logs
    private val sharedFlow = MutableSharedFlow<String>(replay = 64, extraBufferCapacity = 64)
    private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)

    init {
        sharedFlow.onEach { log ->
            println("$log")
            // write to file here
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(100) // simulate writing to file
        }.launchIn(scope)
    }

    fun log(message: String) {
        sharedFlow.tryEmit(message) 
    }
}

fun test() {

    val logger = Logger()

    repeat(10) { item ->
        logger.log("Log $item")
    }
}
```

Need to be sure there are enough elements set to `replay` and `extraBufferCapacity` parameters of `MutableSharedFlow` to handle all logs.